# Is the UITableView an appropriate control for building a UI like the Facebook app?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uikit

I'm looking to build a UI similar to that of the Facebook app seen below.

[image]

Is the UITableView appropriate to create this layout? Can it be customised enough to give this style or is there another layout (some kind of vertical stack panel)?

Comment: Yes u can,look at this one it is tableview http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mgbox , and the same for all this http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=tableview

Answer (score 2):

Yes absolutely.

Tableview is used in most apps not just to display data but to create UI layouts too.

To make it easier look into creating a UITableViewCell subclass and doing all the layout of the cell within this subclass.

Doing this keeps the UITableViewController code smaller and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes u can,look at this one it is tableview** http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mgbox ,

and the same for all this http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=tableview.

By changing cell height dynamic:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath;
{
}
```